# How to use Windows Libre office Macro In Linux environment

Tags: linux, macros, libreoffice

I have some macro which I have made in libre office by window 7
Now I want to run those macro in Linux system through some kind of command

Now issue is that How can I save Macro in a single file..?

when I am writing macro It is saving in "My Macro and Dialogues" in Libre office i think (I don't know)

I want to save macro in file, not in Libre office library 
I tried to make macro like this but It's not running properly , it's run Only first step which I have made for Open File , After that It's not running.

If I can macro run In File so I can use that macro in any other system
But this time How can I save macro in local file instaed of LO library

Simple  :  How to save macro In local file instead of LO library, So I can use that macro in My another Computer system

Comment: Here is similar thread [Use Windows Macro into Linux Evironment](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/50511/use-windows-macro-into-linux-evironment/) check whether this helps.

Comment: That thread also mine but I didn't get proper answer DUDE